# Quando um struct 'clonado' é mudado altera todos os outros

Tags: c, memória, struct, clone

Tenho as seguintes declarações:

```
#define SCALE 4
#define PADDING 1.1

#define CUBES 27
#define CUBE_VERTICES 8
#define CUBE_FACES 6
#define FACE_VERTICES 4

typedef struct {
  float angle;
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
} Rotate;

typedef struct {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
} Vertice;

typedef struct {
  int vertices[4];
  float red;
  float green;
  float blue;
} Face;

typedef struct {
  Vertice vertices[8];
  Face faces[6];
  Rotate rotate;
} Cube;

float rotate_y = 0;
float rotate_x = 0;
int mode = 1;
float rotate_angle = 5;
Cube cubes[27];
```

Onde defino algumas variáveis onde as mais importantes são os `structs` e o array de `Cube`.

Vou descrever rapidamente o que estou fazendo assim fica mais fácil para a compreensão de todos,um cube (`Cube`) é composto por 8 vértices ou pontos (`Vertice`), por 6 faces(`Face`) e uma rotação(`Rotate`), por sua vez, cada `Vertice` possui coordenadas (x,y,z), cada `Face` possui uma coloração e um conjunto de indicadores de vértices, que irão mostrar quais vértices do `Cube` forma aquela face, e cada `Rotate` possui o angulo de rotação e qual eixo irá rodar.

Tendo essas informações do cubo eu posso passar essa estrutura para o *openGL* desenhar ele na tela. Meu projeto é fazer um cubo mágico, então teria 27 cubos, por isso o `array` de cubos.

Então pensei em criar apenas o primeiro cubo, e então clonar o restante mudando apenas as coordenadas das vértices dele. Vamos ao processo de criar o primeiro cubo:

```
Cube createCube(Cube c) {
  // criando vertices de cima
  // vertice          cria         X      Y    Z
  c.vertices[0] = createVertice(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  c.vertices[1] = createVertice(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
  c.vertices[2] = createVertice(0.5, 0.5, -0.5);
  c.vertices[3] = createVertice(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5);

  // criando vertices de baixo
  // vertice          cria         X      Y    Z
  c.vertices[4] = createVertice(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
  c.vertices[5] = createVertice(0.5, -0.5, 0.5);
  c.vertices[6] = createVertice(0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
  c.vertices[7] = createVertice(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5);

  // cima e baixo
  // face       cria          determina vertices         R  G  B
  c.faces[0] = createFace(verticesFromFace(1, 2, 3, 4), 0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
  c.faces[1] = createFace(verticesFromFace(5, 6, 7, 8), 0.8, 1.0, 0.2);

  // direita e esquerda
  // face       cria          determina vertices         R  G  B
  c.faces[2] = createFace(verticesFromFace(1, 4, 8, 5), 0.2, 0.4, 0.8);
  c.faces[3] = createFace(verticesFromFace(2, 3, 7, 6), 0.2, 0.8, 0.4);

  // fundo e frente
  // face       cria          determina vertices         R  G  B
  c.faces[4] = createFace(verticesFromFace(1, 2, 6, 5), 0.9, 0.0, 0.2);
  c.faces[5] = createFace(verticesFromFace(4, 3, 7, 8), 1.0, 0.3, 0.1);

  c.rotate = createRotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  return c;
}
```

Nesse método eu apenas vou criando um cubo, passando dados de cada vértice, de cada face e a sua rotação. Os métodos chamados no interior desses são:

```
Vertice createVertice(float x, float y, float z) {
  Vertice v;
  v.x = x;
  v.y = y;
  v.z = z;
  return v;
}

Face createFace(int vertices[4], float red, float green, float blue) {
  Face f;
  f.vertices[0] = vertices[0];
  f.vertices[1] = vertices[1];
  f.vertices[2] = vertices[2];
  f.vertices[3] = vertices[3];
  free(vertices);
  f.red = red;
  f.green = green;
  f.blue = blue;
  return f;
}

Rotate createRotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z) {
  Rotate r;
  r.angle = angle;
  r.x = x;
  r.y = y;
  r.z = z;
  return r;
}
```

Eles criam uma determinada `struct`, passando os dados para a mesma e retornando ela.

Com o primeiro cubo criado, eu vou clonar os demais:

```
void createAndCloneCubes() {
  cubes[0] = createCube(cubes[0]);
  cubes[1] = cloneCube(cubes[0], PADDING, 0, 0);
  cubes[2] = cloneCube(cubes[0], -PADDING, 0, 0);

  cubes[9] = cloneCube(cubes[0], 0, 0, -PADDING);
  cubes[10] = cloneCube(cubes[1], 0, 0, -PADDING);
  cubes[11] = cloneCube(cubes[2], 0, 0, -PADDING);

  cubes[18] = cloneCube(cubes[0], 0, 0, PADDING);
  cubes[19] = cloneCube(cubes[1], 0, 0, PADDING);
  cubes[20] = cloneCube(cubes[2], 0, 0, PADDING);

  cubes[3] = cloneCube(cubes[0], 0, PADDING, 0);
  cubes[4] = cloneCube(cubes[1], 0, PADDING, 0);
  cubes[5] = cloneCube(cubes[2], 0, PADDING, 0);

  cubes[12] = cloneCube(cubes[3], 0, 0, -PADDING);
  cubes[13] = cloneCube(cubes[4], 0, 0, -PADDING);
  cubes[14] = cloneCube(cubes[5], 0, 0, -PADDING);

  cubes[21] = cloneCube(cubes[3], 0, 0, PADDING);
  cubes[22] = cloneCube(cubes[4], 0, 0, PADDING);
  cubes[23] = cloneCube(cubes[5], 0, 0, PADDING);

  cubes[6] = cloneCube(cubes[0], 0, -PADDING, 0);
  cubes[7] = cloneCube(cubes[1], 0, -PADDING, 0);
  cubes[8] = cloneCube(cubes[2], 0, -PADDING, 0);

  cubes[15] = cloneCube(cubes[6], 0, 0, -PADDING);
  cubes[16] = cloneCube(cubes[7], 0, 0, -PADDING);
  cubes[17] = cloneCube(cubes[8], 0, 0, -PADDING);

  cubes[24] = cloneCube(cubes[6], 0, 0, PADDING);
  cubes[25] = cloneCube(cubes[7], 0, 0, PADDING);
  cubes[26] = cloneCube(cubes[8], 0, 0, PADDING);
}
```

O primeiro eu crio, e os demais eu clono, passo por parâmetro o cubo a ser clonado, e depois a distância entre um e outro em cada eixo(x,y,z).

O método para clonar o cubo é o seguinte:

```
Cube cloneCube(Cube input, float appX, float appY, float appZ) {
  int i;
  Cube output;
  for (i = 0; i < CUBE_VERTICES; i++)
    output.vertices[i] =
        createVertice(input.vertices[i].x + appX, input.vertices[i].y + appY,
                      input.vertices[i].z + appZ);

  for (i = 0; i < CUBE_FACES; i++) {
    output.faces[i] = createFace(
        verticesFromFace(input.faces[i].vertices[0], input.faces[i].vertices[1],
                         input.faces[i].vertices[2],
                         input.faces[i].vertices[3]),
        input.faces[i].red, input.faces[i].green, input.faces[i].blue);
  }

  output.rotate = createRotate(input.rotate.angle, input.rotate.x,
                               input.rotate.y, input.rotate.z);

  return output;
}
```

Onde crio um novo cubo, parrando as informações do antigo para ele, com observação que nas vértices eu adiciono o espaçamento entre um cubo e outro.

Bom, finalmente, depois de explicar todo meu fluxo de programa, eu vou falar o real problema, depois de todo esse código, eu desenho os cubos com o openGL, até aí tudo bem, o cubo é gerado, mas em certos momentos eu preciso trocar a rotação de um cubo, então tento o seguinte código:

```
if (key == '9' && mode == 2) {
    Rotate r;
    r.angle = -90;
    r.x = 0;
    r.y = 0;
    r.z = 1;
    cubes[16].rotate = r;
} else if (key == '0' && mode == 2) {
    cubes[16].rotate = createRotate(90, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Acima tenho duas tentativas de que se equivalem, de mudar a rotação do cubo número 16, mas ao trocar a rotação do mesmo, todos cubos clonados desse ou do que esse foi clonado(7) também estão alterando o valor de sua rotação. Por exemplo, o cubo 16 foi criado assim:

```
cubes[16] = cloneCube(cubes[7], 0, 0, -PADDING);
```

Então ao mudar a rotação dele, a rotação do cubes[7], cubes[25], cubes[1] (pois o 7 foi clonado dele) e outros também está mudando. Provavelmente a rotação de todos cubos clonados estão com o mesmo endereço de mémoria do seu cubo de origem. Mas não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro, como faço para que cada cubo tenha mesmo sua própria rotação, mesmo que ela tenha ido clonada de outro cubo?

**P.S.:** Desculpem a pergunta estar gigante, mas tentei fazer o melhor para que possam entender tudo e me ajudarem.

Comment: Reparei numa coisa: por que esse `free(vertices)`? Você fez algum `malloc()` antes? Caso não, periga causar problemas no seu programa.

Comment: Sim, no método `verticesFromFace()` que esqueci de colocar eu estou alocando um vetor de 4 posições com o `malloc`

Comment: O @Emoon perguntou isso porque isso não é normal, conforme eu tinha dito na resposta anterior, note como fica esquisito fazer desta forma. Eu acho que está faltando fazer um [mcve] pra eu me interessar pela pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que C, ao contráriode linguagens de mais alto-nível com suporte nativo a orientação a objetos, não "cria" objetos independentes para você só com a sintaxe da linguagem - você tem que fazer isso manualmente.

Então quando você declara suas estruturas de dados estáticamente dentro das suas funções, como em:

```
Vertice createVertice(float x, float y, float z) {
  Vertice v;
  ...
  return v;
}
```

O compilador reserva espaço de memória para uma ùnica estrutura "Vertice" no corpo da função createvertice. Quando a função for chamada de novo, a mesma estrutura é utilizada em memória, no mesmo lugar - e dados alterados nela, vão alterar dados em outros vértices que você tenha retornado em invocações anteriores.

A linguagem C até suporta cópia de structs e arrays de tamanho limitado quando sao passados como parâmetros "por valor" e usados dos dois lados do sinal de igual, como você está (ab)usando no seu código. Isso só evita que seu comportamento seja ainda mais maluco, e faz com que o seu programa possa chegar a ser executado - senão, provavelmente travaria antes disso.

Eu realmente nao consegui identificar em que ponto no seu programa vpode estar acotnecendo algo diferente que faz com que uma das estruturas não seja atribuida do jeito normal pelo compilador - que faz a cópia de cada campo da estrutura - mas pode apostar que o problema está relacionado com isso. Possivelmente há algum problema já que você mistura o uso de malloc no meio e m pelo menos um lugar - e o erro pode estar lá.   (Alias, sua função `createRotate` é completamente redundante para os casos em que você vai copiar os dados de outra struct  `Rotate` - o assignment com `=` já vai copiar os campos da struct de origem)

Bom - basicamente, o que você tem que ter noção é o seguinte: os tipos de dados suportados diretamente pela arquitetura da CPU são os que podem e devem ser usados normalmente "por valor" em chamadas de função em C - e são copiados automaticamente quando "chegam" dentro de uma função e no retorno.

Tirando esses tipos nativos, o correto em qualquer código é você alocar o espaço para suas estruturas de dados manualmente, com `malloc` e passar *sempre* seus objetos por referência.

Isso, ntre outras coisas,  vai deixar o código que você enxerga no seu programa muito mais próximo do que o código de máquina *real* criado pelo compilador C - que é exatametne a vantagem matadora de se codificar em C: vocễ sabe o que a CPU está fazendo. Em código como o seu, quando você faz algo como cubos[0] = createCube(...) - ao retornar o Cubo da função, o compilador C tem que colocar "inline" em código de máquina, o código para copiar cada campo de cada estrutura aninhada dentro do cubo - são centenas de instruções de código de máquina, repetidas para cada um dos 27 cubos que você clona. Então, apesar do impacto disso em tamanho do código em máquinas modernas ser neglígivel, e em performance menos ainda, é algo bastante "deselegante".  Da mesma forma, quando você passa uma estrutura por valor para uma função, o compilador tem que gerar código para copiar recursivamente todos os campos.

Então - o "normal" é você, sim, criar seus objetos com malloc e passar sempre por referẽncia para uma função - cada função que "criar" um novo objeto passa aloca memória NOVA para o objeto em uma outra posição da memória, e retorna um único valor que é um endereço de meória exclusivo daquele objeto.

Você pode até usar suas structs aninhadas "por valor" como estão (isso é, um Cubo ter de fato um array de 6 faces dentro, e não seis ponteiros para seis objetos face) - mas então o seu construtor de cubo tem que dar conta disso.Mas pode ser mais consistente e mais fácil escrever tudo nesse estilo:

```
typedef struct {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
} Vertice;

... 

#define vertices_per_cube 8
typedef struct {
  Vertice *vertices[8];
  Face faces[6];
  Rotate rotate;
} Cube;


Vertice * createVertice(float x, float y, float z) {
    Vertice * output = malloc(sizeof(Vertice));
    if (output == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory - program will crash :-p  ");
    }
    output->x = x; output->y = y; output->z = z;
    return output;
}

Vertice cloneVertice(Vertice * input) {
    Vertice * output = malloc(sizeof(Vertice));
    if (output == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory - program will crash :-p  ");
    }
    output->x = input->x; output->y = input->y; output->z = input->z;
    return output;
}

void * destroyVertice(Vertice * vertice) {
    free(vertice);
}

...

Cube * createCube(Vertice * vertices, Faces * faces, Rotate * rotate) {
    int i;
    Cube * output = malloc(sizeof(Cube));
    if (output == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough memory - program will crash :-p  ");
    }

    for (i=0; i < vertices_per_cube; i++) {
        output->vertices[i] = cloneVertice(vertices[i]);
    }
    ...
    return output;

}
...
void destroyCube(Cube * cube) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < vertices_per_cube; i++) {
        destroyVertice(cube->vertices[i]);
    }
    // code to destroy Faces
    ...
    destroyRotate(cube->Rotate);
    free(cube);
}
```

E então, para cada objeto que você criar, voce detroi quando acabar de usa-lo - em geral dentro da mesma função que foi responsável pela sua criação. 
O fato de você no seu código ter um malloc de um lado, para criar seu vetor de vértices, e um `free` de outro lado, completamente assimétrico, é algo que indica um código muito dificil de ser escrito corretamente e extremamente propenso a erros. Uma alternativa é ter em todos os seus objetos uma contagem de quantas referências a ele existem - e somente quando o número de referências chegar a zero, você o destroi - 
Perceba que - em pouquissimo tempo - você quer ter funçoes genéricas para criar, alocar memporia, gerenciar o tempo de vida, e destruir seus objetos - é dessa necessidade que nasceram as linguagens com suporte a orientação a objetos embutido - ou mesmo, frameworks em C para trabalhar com objetos, onde muito desse trabalho é feito por macros.  (um exemplo é a GLIB)

Em suma - se quiser fazer esse tipo de coisa em  C, é melhor fazer do "jeito certo" - mesmo que signifique suar a camisa. Por outro lado, só vale a pena fazer isso em C para (1) justamente entender e treinar esses mecanismos (fins didáticos) - ou se você for rodar o código em hardware muito limitado (IoT).

Comment: (enquanto estava escrevendo, e depois desta versão da resposta, fiz algumas buscas sobre passagem de estruturas por valor - e a coisa é meio unânime: ocmpiladores modernos permitem isso - mas ninguém usa muito, pelos motivos acima e outros. **Entretanto** para estruturas pequenas, ~16 bytes, é possível que  o compilador possa gerar código bastante otimizado para a cópia.  Verifique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161788/are-there-any-downsides-to-passing-structs-by-value-in-c-rather-than-passing-a

Comment: Estava olhando aqui, parece que o problema estava no OpenGL e não no código, acontecia que quando eu mudava a rotação de um cubo no openGL ele mudava a rotação de todos os outros seguintes, mesmo quando eu resetava o ângulo, mas consegui arrumar. Não teve haver com a estrutura que postei aqui, ela está funcionando bem. Sobre as 'criticas', eu tentei fazer de maneira diferente, para tornar o codigo mais legível no openGL, certificando que todo malloc é liberado, etc.

Comment: Sobre os destroy, no caso não é necessário, pois eu preciso usar esse array de cubos em todos os lugares, no programa inteiro, por exemplo, quando o usuário aperta uma tecla eu rotaciono 9 cubos, dai eu uso essas informações do array para rotacionar, so pararia de usar ele quando l programa for fechado mesmo.